# How can I search for inserted files in a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a long Microsoft Word document with many inserted files. Is there a way to search for inserted files in the document? I tried searching for the file extension (CSV) using Find, but that resulted in no hits, so the inserted file name must not be visible to the Find command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a macro to iterate over all [InlineShapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220969(v=office.11).aspx)

```
 Sub AllInlineShapes()

  For Each o In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
      If o.Type = 1 Then
        Debug.Print o.Type,
        If Not o.OLEFormat Is Nothing Then
          Debug.Print o.OLEFormat.ClassType,
        End If
        If Not o.LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print o.LinkFormat.SourceFullName,
        End If
        Debug.Print "."
      End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Or for an Docx file you could make a copy and change its file extension to .zip. With the file explorer or an zipviewer you should find the files in the folder `\DocMedia`

Comment: I would never have thought of this so thanks. Maybe a future version of Word will be better integrated with inserted files.